# How can I display the list of the search results under the input element?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I want to display the results of the search in list-group (Bootstrap) under the input, where I'm, [hovering my mouse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOZc1.gif).

If I make a list after the search div, [it starts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iO9g4.png) at the top of the screen.

How can I position the list below the search?

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  font-family: 'Cutive Mono', monospace;
}

.search {
  top: 37%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">

  <div class="search">
    INPUT
  </div>

  <div class="list-group">
    LIST ITEMS
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: The `.search` element is positioned absolutely, so it's removed from the document flow. You may want to include the list inside the absolutely positioned element, or structure the document differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you're using `position:absolute` to center the input vertically and horizontally. However, absolute positioning removes an element from the document flow, so positioning another element relative to that one may have seemingly unexpected results.

> **absolute**
>   The element is removed from the normal document flow; no space is created for the element in the page layout.
>   -- [position @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

---

One alternative idea is to use a [flexible box layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout). The `.content` element becomes a "flex container" and its two children are horizontally and vertically centered within their parent.

Below, I've used the [Bootstrap flex classes](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/).

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Cutive Mono', monospace;
}

.search {
  margin: 0 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="content d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">

  <div class="search">
    <input type="text" placeholder="search">
  </div>

  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">Test</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Another Test</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Sample</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Another Sample</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Last one</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```